# Algorithm to round two numbers to the nearest evenly divisible ones

Tags: c#, math, rounding

The title is not really well phrased, I'm aware - can't think of a better way of writing it though.

Here's the scenario - I have two input boxes, both representing integer quantities. One is represented in our units, the other in the vendor's units. There is a multiplier defining how to convert from ours to theirs. In the below example, I'm saying that two of our units is equal to five of theirs. So, for example,

```
decimal multiplier = 0.4; // Two of our units equals five of theirs
int requestedQuantity = 11; // Our units
int suppliedQuantity = 37; // Their units

// Should return 12, since that is the next highest whole number that results in both of us having whole numbers (12 of ours = 30 of theirs)
int correctedFromRequestedQuantity = GetCorrectedRequestedQuantity(requestedQuantity, null, multiplier); 

// Should return 16, since that is the next highest whole number that results in both of us having whole numbers (16 of ours = 40 of theirs);
int correctedFromSuppliedQuantity = GetCorrectedRequestedQuantity(suppliedQuantity, multiplier, null);
```

Here's the function I've written to handle this. I'm not doing a divide by zero check on the multiplier / rounder since I've already checked for that elsewhere. It seems crazy to do all that converting, but is there a better way of doing it?

```
public int GetCorrectedRequestedQuantity(int? input, decimal? multiplier, decimal? rounder)
{
  if (multiplier == null)
  {
    if (rounder == null)
      return input.GetValueOrDefault();
    else
      return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)((decimal)Math.Ceiling(input.GetValueOrDefault() / rounder.Value) * rounder.Value));
  }
  else if (input.HasValue)
  {
    // This is insane...
    return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)((decimal)Math.Ceiling((int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)input * multiplier.Value) / multiplier.Value) * multiplier.Value));
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If something can be devided without rest, is easiset checked with the Modulo Operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator- | Of course with Double, you ahve to deal with Floating Point Inprecision: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: The rules and current processing steps are very unclear. Please add a lot of comments to explain what you are doing.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I added some more comments, please let me know if I can clarify any further. Basically the challenge is to get the input (either in their units or ours) to result in both our units and their units being whole numbers, based on the multiplier.

Answer (score 2):

Represent the multiplier as a fraction in lowest terms. I don't know if .NET has a fractions class but if not you can probably find a C# implementation, or just write your own. So assume the multiplier is given by two integers *a / b* in lowest terms, with a ≠ 0 and b ≠ 0. That also means that conversion in the other direction is given by multiplying by *b / a*. In your example, *a* = 2 and *b* = 5, and *a / b* = 0.4.

Now suppose you want to convert an integer *X*. If you think about it a bit you'll see what you really want is to nudge *X* up until *b* divides *X*. The number you need to add to *X* is simply *(b - (X%b)) % b*. So to convert on one direction is just

```
return (a * (X + (b - (X % b) % b))) / b;
```

and to convert *Y* going in the other direction is just

```
return (b * (Y + (a - (X % a) % a))) / a;
```

Comment: I would not call any formula with 4 Elipses "simple". Indeed I am not even sure what you are calculating here. | I did have an idea to make it run without a loop. Using the inverse of a Modulo for the rounding up is a very good idea.

Comment: @Christopher: I wouldn't call it simple either. I called a piece of it "simple", but that piece wasn't really simple either. I called it simple so OP wouldn't be intimidated. I might try to add a little more explanatory text. Thanks for your commentary.

Comment: Actually, @Christopher, I might delete my answer because it's not what OP is looking for. I guess I don't yet understand what OP is looking for.

Comment: Leave it. It was the only reason I got my answer working.

Comment: I'm pretty much on board with this approach, although I think that for the purpose of verifying the results, it would be useful to separate some of the terms into assignments to intermediate variables, so that one can look at the intermediate results and see that they agree with stuff that's done by hand.

Answer (score 0):

My best idea of my head is to semi brute-force it. It does sound like it is basically [Fraction Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)). So there might be a way easier solution for this.

First we need to find in what sort of "Batch" the multiplier becomes whole. That way, we can stop working with floats/doubles altogether. Ideally this should be supplied with the multiplier (as float math is messy).

```
double currentMultiple=multiplier;
int currentCount=0;

//This is the best check for "is an integer" could think off.
while(currentMultiple % 1 = 0){
  //The Framework can detect Arithmetic Overflow. Let us turn that one on
  //If we ever get there, likely the math is non-solveable
  checked{
    currentMultiple+= multiplier;
    currentCount += 1;
  }
}

//You get here either via exception or because you got a multiple that solves it.
//Store the value of currentCount into a variable "OurBatchSize"
//Also store the value of currentMultiple in "TheirBatchSize"
```

Getting the closest Multiple of OurBatchSize:

```
int requestedQuantity = 11; // Our units
int result = OurBatchSize;
int batchCount = 0;

while(temp < requestedQuantity){
  result += OurBatchSize;
  batchCount++
}

//result contains the answer here. Return it
//batchCount * TheirBatchSize will also tell you how much they get.
```

Edit: Credit for this goes mostly to James Reinstate Monica Polk. He had the math idea to use Modulo for this. Here is what I got with explanation:

```
int result;
int rest = requestedAmout % BatchSize;
if (rest != 0){
  //Correct upwards to the next multiple
  int DistanceToNextMultiple = BatchSize - Rest;
  result = requestedAmout + DistanceToMultiple;
}
else{
  //It already is right
  result = requestedAmout;
}
```

For the BatchSize of 4, you will get:

- 13; 13%4=1; 4-1=3; 13+3=16;
- 14; 14%4=2; 4-2=2; 14+2=16;
- 15; 15%4=3; 4-3=1; 15+1=16;
- 16; 16%4=0; Else is used. 16 is already right.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for the answer - I'm trying as much as possible to avoid needing to use a while loop though. Realistically it should function just fine, but it feels like there should be a much more elegant way of doing this :/

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy If it was just rounding up, code like "(int/int)+1" would do it. You could use "(int/int)" as your start point/approxmiation. And only counting up until a perfect match that fullfills `candidate % OurBatchSize == 0`

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy I am actually sure it is not solveable without a loop. A human can quickly draw the next closest value from memory in most cases. But computers? They *have* to loop. If you could pre-generate the list of possible values (4, 8, 12, 16, 20), you could turn this into a memory access problem. But those are still a loop. But somewhere, somehow the CPU has to loop.

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy `Math.InternalRound()` - the one doing the actuall work behind the double variant of `Math.Round()` - uses a shortcut. But I am unsure if you can translate it to something usefull.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,f0afe85387e48317

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy Found another solution, using math and a simple if.